# drupal CDN module not altering URLs

Tags: cdn

I'm using Drupal 7 on an Ubuntu VPS, I'm trying to setup CDN module with Rackspace cloud files. I'm using file conveyor and the whole setup going well. the only problem I have that Drupal CDN module not altering the files url to use the cdn urls. it still use local files. 
- the files already synced to rackspace.
- file conveyor working fine.
- Drupal CDN configured correctly  and it show me that it sees file conveyor working and it's sees the sync file database.

- more details about the issue: I'm using multisite setup and I'm using file conveyor with the public files folder.

Any Advice? Thanks

Comment: Is it all the files? Or just some? Like do your CSS/JS not work, but images do? Have you cleared your cache?

Comment: yes cache cleared, and no files came out of the cdn. I'm using the cdn files for the public files folder not everything

Comment: How are you making the URLs?  Manually or file_create_url()?

Comment: I don't have any custom modules or files yet, but I'm on any file stored in the public files folder. like an image in the image field : /sites/mysite.com/files/styles/medium/public/field/image/imagefield_c3ayN8.jpg

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you have a setting or two wrong.  On admin/config/development/cdn make sure you are enabled, and not in testing mode:

[image]

Then goto admin/config/development/cdn/other, expand all of the sections and make sure you aren't excluding actual pages.

Comment: Yes , these are correct, CDN Enabled and nothing excluded